# mysql to PDO conversion

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am converting old mysql to PDO.

Old working code:

```
$sql='INSERT INTO `plat_wiadomosci`( `wiad_oddzial`, `temat`, `tresc`,`id_user`,`ip`,`data_wiadomosci`,`wiad_telefon`,`wiad_zrobiony`) VALUES ("'.$_POST['tt'].'","'.$tytul.'","'.$_POST['wiadomosc'].'","'.$_POST['did'].'","'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'","'.time().'","'.$_POST['telefon'].'","0")';
mysql_query($sql);
```

New code in PDO:

```
$stmt=$db->prepare('INSERT INTO `plat_wiadomosci`( `wiad_oddzial`, `temat`, `tresc`,`id_user`,`ip`,`data_wiadomosci`,`wiad_telefon`,`wiad_zrobiony`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,"'.time().'",?,"0")');
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['tt'],$tytul,$_POST['wiadomosc'],$_POST['did'],$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$_POST['telefon']));
```

First code is writing into database the other won't, any suggestion ?

Connection:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname12.';charset=utf8', $dbuser23, $dbpsw34);
$db->exec("set names utf8");
```

After error info:
i pasted after exec, print_r($db->errorInfo());
i get

```
Array ( [0] => 00000 )
```

Comment: In prepare statement in your values put all ? and in your array pass all the value that you want.

Comment: tested won't change anything

Comment: Just curious -  why use php's time() insted of MySQL's NOW()?

Comment: Look carefully at the `prepare` method signature...

Comment: Can we see the connection?

Comment: At first you need to get error message.